# manipulation of data in R using data.table or dplyr with groupby and subsetting of dates

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm looking for some help with data.table and/or dplyr. I have a data frame like this:

```
Name     Date          X      Y
Mike     2016-10-21    3.2    1.6
Mike     2016-10-23    3.1    1.4
Mike     2016-10-24    4.9    3.8
Mike     2016-10-25    5.7    4.2
Mike     2016-10-28    0.2   -1.1
Bob      2016-10-21    2.2   -1.1
Bob      2016-10-22    0.2   -3.6
Bob      2016-10-24   -9.2  -14.1
Bob      2016-10-25   -7.2  -12.1
Alice    2016-10-20    7.2    6.1
Alice    2016-10-21    2.2    0.1
Alice    2016-10-23   13.2    8.1
Alice    2016-10-25   12.6    8.8
Alice    2016-10-27    7.7    4.7
Alice    2016-10-28    8.2    5.0
```

I'd like to be able to return the mean of X & Y for each person, however, I'd like to subset it so that it only uses the values from the 3 most recent dates for each person, ignoring the data from older dates. I'd also like to return the number of days there were between these 3 most recent dates. Ideally, I would end up with a data frame like this:

```
Name     DaysBetween   avgX    avgY
Mike               4    3.6     2.3
Bob                3   -5.4    -9.9
Alice              3    9.5     6.2
```

Edit note: This data will always be ordered by date, so we could probably also just take the "last 3" data points for each person instead of trying to use date logic to find which three are the most recent.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Hm have you tried anything that yielded an error or a wrong result?

Comment: No, I haven't. So far, I've only been able to get the averages of X & Y for all data points for each person. But I'm struggling with how to subset for only using the 3 most recent dates. I'm a noob with data.table and dplyr though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[order(-Date), .(DaysBetween = as.integer(Date[1L] - Date[3L]), 
         avgX = mean(X[1:3]), avgY = round(mean(Y[1:3]),2)), by  = Name]
#    Name DaysBetween avgX  avgY
#1:  Mike           4  3.6  2.30
#2: Alice           3  9.5  6.17
#3:   Bob           3 -5.4 -9.93
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. This worked great as well!

Answer (score 1):

The above are all great responses, here is an iterative approach:

```
#initialize the output frame
outputFrame = as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = length(unique(train$Name)),
ncol = 4))

#renaming the data frame
names(outputFrame) = c("Names", "daysBetween", "avgX", "avgY")

#turn the date to a date
train$Date = as.Date(train$Date, "%m/%d/%Y")

#initialize the outputCounter
outputCounter = 1

#iterates over every unique Name in the data frame
for(name in as.character(unique(train$Name)))
{
    #subsets the dataframe into the values of each given level of Name
    dfSubset = train[which(train$Name == name),]

    #Orders the dataframe by date
    dfSubset = dfSubset[order(dfSubset$Date),]

    #get the 3 most recent dates
    dfSubset = dfSubset[(nrow(dfSubset) -2):nrow(dfSubset),]

    #fill the names
    outputFrame$Names[outputCounter] = name

    #fill the days between
    outputFrame$daysBetween[outputCounter] = as.numeric(max(dfSubset$Date) - min(dfSubset$Date))

    #get the average X
    outputFrame$avgX[outputCounter] = mean(dfSubset$X)

    #get the average Y
    outputFrame$avgY[outputCounter] = mean(dfSubset$Y)

    #increment outputCounter
    outputCounter = outputCounter +1
}
```

Assuming train is your dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr::top_n` to filter the data:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(Date = as.Date(Date)) %>%    # parse to Date class, if not already
    group_by(Name) %>% 
    top_n(3, Date) %>%    # filter to max 3 dates for each group
    summarise(DaysBetween = max(Date) - min(Date), 
              avgX = mean(X), 
              avgY = mean(Y))

## # A tibble: 3 × 4
##     Name DaysBetween  avgX      avgY
##   <fctr>      <time> <dbl>     <dbl>
## 1  Alice      3 days   9.5  6.166667
## 2    Bob      3 days  -5.4 -9.933333
## 3   Mike      4 days   3.6  2.300000
```